# Custom bbCode URL

Tags: php, html, bbcode

I made a bbCode replacer and I got stucked with the linking.

```
$replacements[3] = '<a href="\1">\2</a>';
```

It replaces in no time, but with wrong URL... mydomain.com http:\\somelink.com\ 
 What's wrong with this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't actually shown the regex to match it.. but it should be something like:

**Find**

```
"'\[url=(.*?)\](.*?)\[/url\]'i"
```

**Replace**

```
"<a href=\"\\1\">\\2</a>"
```

**Example**

```
preg_replace("'\[url=(.*?)\](.*?)\[/url\]'i", 
             "<a href=\"\\1\">\\2</a>", 
             "[url=www.google.com]Google![/url]"
             );
```

**Output**

```
<a href="www.google.com">Google!</a>
```

**Note**
I purposely don't validate the URL in the regex because it's ugly and not necessary. Validate it using `filter_var(..., FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);`

Comment: Still linking to my site.. only puts a white space and then the link. (mydomain.com http:\\somelink.cok\)

Comment: What is your input? Please see the updated answer for a working example.

Comment: Thank you, found a ” in front of the URL... solved my problem.

Comment: @Zhafur great, feel free to accept the answer if it helped you :)